# How to use a json as a parameter for workflow_dispatch

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to automate some tests but I would need to pass some particular parameters to the final test scripts that would fit perfectly as a json file. The issue now is to make github action able to handle json data as a parameter.

The constraint is that the json file as to be local as the workflow has to be triggered from the command `gh workflow run ...`

So far I tried create my first `yml` file as such :

```
name: setup

on:
  workflow_dispatch :
    inputs:
      config_file:
        description: 'json file containing the configuration for the runners'
        required: true
        type: string
...
env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  setup-auth:
    name: setup-authentication
    uses: ./.github/workflows/single-device-authentication.yml
    with:
      devices: mlops
      config_file: ${{  inputs.config_file }}
    secrets: inherit
```

single-device-authentication.yml looks like this, I commented where it fails :

```
name: single-device-authentication

on: 
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      devices:
        required: true
        type: string
      config_file:
        description: 'json file containing the configuration for jetson runners'
        required: true
        type: string
      

jobs:
  device-authentication:
    name: device-authentication
    runs-on: ${{  inputs.devices }}

    steps:
     - uses: PATH/TO/gh_auth@main
       with:
         app_id: 7
         private_key: ${{ secrets.MLOPS_BOT_PRIVATE_KEY }}

  json-parser:
    name: parser
    runs-on: ${{inputs.devices}}
    needs: device-authentication
    steps:
      - name: parser script
        run: | 
          echo ${{ inputs.config_file }}" # This fails
```

Also, to trigger the workflow, I tried that way :
`gh workflow run setup.yml -f config_file="$(cat ${PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE})"`